# SharePoint 2013 - tagging service is currently unavaialble

Tags: sharepoint, tagging

When attempting to use hashtags in SharePoint 2013 users see "the tagging service is currently unavailable".  I've googled this issue and have tried or validated the following without success:

1. The application pool for Managed Metadata Service is running with the correct credentials
2. The Managed Metadata Web Service is running on all WFE's and app servers
3. In Central Admin the Managed Metadata web service is the default location for keywords

In general this (test) farm looks identical to my production farm.  The only difference is that I've applied the new service pack 1 to this test farm, and now this service appears to have broken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally after installing a service pack, you are required to run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard on each of the servers in the farm ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338%28v=office.15%29.aspx)). Also, sometimes a reboot may be required after running the configuration wizard. Have you done both/either of those things?

Comment: Yes, I've run the products and config wizard on all boxes and have rebooted them (in some cases several times.)